# Django unit Test-case trying to resolve custom-decorator before executing setUpModule

Tags: django-unittest

I'm trying to use a **custom-decorator** in django unit-test case **"@client_login"** before every test-assertion in Django-unit test-case.
I was expecting that "setUpModule " should execute first then Decorator should be resolve .

but Actually test-case loader is trying to resolve decorator first & the loading the setup module .

Is there anyway to load setUpModule forcefully before resolving my **custom decorator**.